# babel unexpected token react module build failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, babel-loader

I have this page:

```js
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import "./Loader.css";

const Loading = ({ loadingMsg, styling }) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="loader">
        <p style={styling}>{loadingMsg}</p>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Loading;
```

I don't know why when I start my project it throws this error:

```sh
ERROR in ./src/components/Loading/Loading.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js): 
Unexpected token (6:4)
```

my babelrcfile:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]

}
```

and my webpack config file:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  target: 'web',
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'] },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    publicPath: "/",
    contentBase: "./public",
    hot: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-inline-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'svg-url-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

i think i have everything good so i don't understand where the issue with this loader file. i already delete the fragment part and when i do that the same error is report on the div.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with Babel config, i.e. it can't interpret JSX. How did you set up your project environment? Did you use create-react-app?

Comment: yes i create it with create-react-app i put my webpack and babel config on the main post!

Comment: I'm confused. If you used create-react-app you wouldn't have your own webpack config unless you ejected, but even then that ejected config is properly configured to interpret JSX and the one you posted is certainly not the CRA one. How do you start your project? `yarn start` which runs `react-scripts start`?

Comment: so you tell me if i use CRA i don't have to setup my own webpack config cause react do itself where i can see the original one?

Comment: Well.. yeah, that's the whole point of create-react-app. It was created so that developers don't have to deal with the config stuff and just start developing. Everything Babel and Webpack related is hidden behind `react-scripts` module. You won't find the original one unless you eject, which you should not do (unless you just want to learn how it looks like, in which case you can either check it on github or run `yarn eject` on a separate project, as it's irreversible).

Comment: Thank you man! i restart my project with CRA method and without create my own webpack config file and everything works!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [babel-preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env) and [babel-preset-react](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react) to your project like this:

```sh
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react
```

Then create a `.babelrc` file with this config:

```js
module.exports = {
    presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
};
```

Comment: what versions of babel and @babel/presets do you have? Also, do you use Create-React-App?

Comment: yes create-react-app and "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",

Comment: what's the version of your @babel/core?

Comment: "@babel/core": "^7.9.6", i use the lastest versions for all

Comment: I'd suggest coming back to version 7.0.0 and see if that solves the issue